Создание прокси-объекта/псевдонима для класса
Моя задача состоит в следующем: IDE должна автоматически определять доступные методы класса, переданного в качестве аргумента в конструктор, а данный конструктор должен как бы обретать те же методы, что и переданный в него класс. Поведение, которого я хочу добиться, крайне схоже с прокси-объектом или псевдонимами (alias) в sqlalchemy. Однако попытки определить, как оно там устроено внутри, не увенчались успехом. Простой пример того, как я хочу видеть эту реализацию:
from typing import Type, Any


class BaseSymbol:
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value = value

    def get_value(self):
        return self.value


class A(BaseSymbol):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("a")

    def get_a(self):
        return super().get_value()


class Alphabet:
    def __init__(self, symbol_type: Type[BaseSymbol] = A):
        self.symbol = symbol_type()

    def __setattr__(self, key: str, value: Any):
        """Позволяет устанавливать атрибуты self.symbol как у Alphabet"""
        if key == "symbol":
            return super().__setattr__(key, value)
        if hasattr(self.session, key):
            return self.session.__setattr__(key, value)
        return super().__setattr__(key, value)

    def __getattr__(self, item: str):
        """Позволяет обращаться к self.symbol как к экземпляру Alphabet"""
        return self.session.__getattribute__(item)


test_instance = Alphabet(A)
# После этого IDE должна предоставлять подсказки о методах класса A, например:
# test_instance. должно отобразить get_a() и value
# при этом если будет создан новый класс например "B" и в нём будет новый метод он тоже должен отобразиться

Пробовал через TypeVar и Generic, но тоже не помогло.
Изменено:
Небольшой пример из sqlalchemy с использованием alias-а:
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import as_declarative, Mapped, mapped_column, aliased


@as_declarative()
class Base:
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
    metadata = MetaData()


class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'

    name: Mapped[str]
    age: Mapped[str]


engine = create_engine("sqlite:///container.db")
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

p = aliased(Person)
print(p.name)  # >>> aliased(Person).name



где именно (на каком фрагменте кода) Вы будете смотреть подсказку в IDE ?

Alphabet() с переданным в него классом(например А) в виде аргумента должен давать те же подсказки, если обращаться напрямую к экземпляру А или Alphabet().symbol

Можете добавить к вопросу либо ссылку либо воспроизводимый пример кода с Alias в sqlalchemy? Потому что как минимум нужно убедиться, что то что сделано у них совпадает с вашей задумкой, на этот счет у меня есть определенные сомнения так как типизирование (подсказки) в IDE достигается статическим анализом, а в вашем случае нужен запуск кода.

Может я недостаточно точно выразился, запуск кода не нужен, мне надо именно подсказки для пользователей во время написания кода. То есть, во время написания кода, если я напишу Alphabet(A) и после напишу точку что бы обратиться к методу или полю данного экземпляра Alphabet IDE должно мне подсказать методы и поля которые есть в переданном классе(то есть A), а не только Alphabet как это происходит обычно.

Правильно Вы выразились, возможно я не донес свою мысль) Дело в том чтобы что-то появилось после ввода точки IDE должно получить данные что там может появится составить тот самый список. Так вот ваш код написан так что для получения свойств и методов нужно его исполнение, IDE узнать не сможет так как самостоятельный запуск кода не осуществляет — нужны другие механизмы. Если Вы укажете то место где вы видели подобное, то возможно я помогу Вам решить эту задачу, но я сомневаюсь что это две одинаковые задачи потому что по сути вы ставите точку после того как сработает конструктор т.е. в runtime

@DaniilLoban добавил небольшой пример из sqlalcemy. Хотя теперь уже и я сомневаюсь что это две одинаковые задачи, хоть и поведение крайне похожее на желаемое...

Да, по-моему сходство задач если и есть то совсем не очевидно, если aliased(Person) возвращает тип Person то поведение не вызывает вопросов как тут допустим. Кстати пример как раз на генериках.
